# Path properties of Levy Processes

Tags: pr.probability

I would appreciate if someone helps me with introducing a reference explaining the path properties of Levy Processes. In other words, I want to know a good interpretation of the Levy - Khintchine formula.

Comment: Rogers & Williams's 2-volume book would be my first port of call, though I admit I can't remember precisely what they say about Levy-Khintchine

Comment: Either Applebaum's or Kyprianou's book should help you:

http://www.amazon.com/Processes-Stochastic-Calculus-Cambridge-Mathematics/dp/0521832632

http://www.amazon.com/Introductory-Fluctuations-Processes-Applications-Universitext/dp/3540313427/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1339149652&sr=1-1

Also Kallemberg's "Foundations of Modern Probability" devotes a chapter to infinitely divisible random variables (i.e Levy Kintchine Formula)



Comment: @ Hassan : I think that Sato's book is the best reference on the subject. Best regards

Comment: @ Yemon Choi, Felipe Olmos, The Bridge: Thanks guys for your help. I already study "Levy Processes & Stochastic Calculus by D. Applebaum", you know this book goes more in details and theory behind Levy - Khintchine... but I'm looking for a reference explaining the properties of paths. For example, I'm working on some application of Levy processes in Finance and insurance so i need some properties of Levy paths...

Comment: @Hassan: please register so you can merge duplicate accounts

Answer (score 2):

Phil Protter also has a book (I don't recall if it discusses path properties).  If you just want more information on the Skorokhod space (cadlag functions), P. Billingsley's convergence of probability measures is a good book.  If you want path properties of more general stable processes (which are not necessarily Levy, i.e. may not have stationary and indpt increments) then Samorodnitsky and Taqqu have a chapter on path properties.

Comment: @ Paul, Thanks man for your help. I'm gonna take a look at the book by" Taqqu".

Comment: @Hassan before you delve into that book (ST94), let me reiterate that it considers stable processes generally.  What many people refer to as THE stable process is called alpha-stable Levy motion in ST94.  That and stable subordinators might possibly be the only Levy processes they consider in their path property analysis (chapters 9-12).